# How can I get my WordPress template to recognize my JS frameworks?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, wordpress

I created a custom template called Contact-Us and uploaded it to my WordPress theme directory.

The template called Contact-Us.php was created with the ability to add more rows dynamically using AngularJS.

It also uses Bootstrap framework for page layout.

Everything looks and works good.

Before uploading it to my WordPress theme folder, I knew that I had to separate the styles both inline and the ones with external references.

I also knew I had to do same with the AngularJS and Boostrap frameworks as well as jQuery libraries.

I followed the instructions from the following link:

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/how-to-create-a-built-in-contact-form-for-your-wordpress-theme

The issue is the page is complete mis-aligned and the AngularJS functionality that dynamically creates and removes new roles is no longer working.

I know I am doing something wrong even though I followed the instructions from that link.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Below is how I tried to add those js libraries on header.php

My code is just below the header hook.

addrows.js is the the Angular code that creates the dynamic rows.

Guys, I still need your assistance with this code.

I have updated the code. Right now, I am not getting any errors.

However, the code is not doing the things it is supposed to do.

First, it is supposed to lay out the page nicely as it does with the html version.

Second, the code is supposed to allow users to click to Add additional textboxes.

When you click the **Add More** button, nothing happens.

All these lead me to believe the js and css files are not being recognized.

The script below is placed inside function.php.

Can someone please look at the script and see if you can tell me why my css and js files not being recognized?

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts_styles');
function scripts_styles(){
   if (!is_admin()){
     if(is_page_template('Contact-Us.php')){
       wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapcss', 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.3', 'all');
       wp_enqueue_style('maincss', BASE_URL . '/css/main.css');
       wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
       wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
       wp_enqueue_script('handlebars', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.min.js', array(), null, true);
       wp_enqueue_script('addrows', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/addrows.js', array(), null, true);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to add stylesheets and scripts is to use the WordPress built-in functions, **wp_enqueue_scripts** and **wp_enqueue_styles**.

In your case to add the scripts you can follow the code below, and put it in your **functions.php** file.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts_and_styles', 999 );
functions theme_scripts_and_styles() {
   if (!is_admin()) {
     if(is_page_template('Contact-Us.php') {
       wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
       wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
       wp_enqueue_script('handlebars', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/handlebars.min.js', array(), null, true);
       wp_enqueue_script('addrows', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/addrows.js', array(), null, true);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it blew up my wordpress app.

Fortunately, I had a back up copy. WOW

Comment: I don't think that code would be able to blew up something :D. I think when you pasted the code it generated a syntax error, and make sure to set the WP_DEBUG to **TRUE**  in the wp-options.php to properly diagnose the issue.

Comment: I did as you instructed and got the following. Please see bottom of original post.

Do you know how I can resolve it?

Comment: I have updated my code and comments above. Can anyone please help?